# Jackson JSON mapping of superclass value

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am using Jackson 1.8.3 in a Spring application to map Java Objects to JSON.

One of my Java Class (`Child`) extends an super class (`Parent`) that is part of an Libary, so I am not able to modify it. (Especially I am not able to add annotations.)

I am using `@JsonAutoDetect(JsonMethod.NONE)` because I need only a small set of fields from the object, instead I am using `@JsonProperty`.

```
class Parent {
  public long getId(){...};
  ...
}

@JsonAutoDetect(JsonMethod.NONE)
class Child extends Parent {

    @JsonProperty
    private String title;
}
```

**But one of the fields I need is an field `id` from the superclass, but I don't know how to tell Jackson to pay attention to this field, without modifying the parent class (because I can not modify it).**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am not able to add annotations

You can add annotations using mix-ins.  See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations for details.

Depending on what the rest of the class feild/method structures are, another approach that might work would be to configure visibility access of fields/methods through ObjectMapper.  The following line demonstrates how to make such a configuration, not necessarily the specific configuration you need.

```
mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getVisibilityChecker().withFieldVisibility(Visibility.ANY));
```

> I am using @JsonAutoDetect(JsonMethod.NONE) because I need only a small set of fields from the object, instead I am using @JsonProperty

I should have realized that was possible.  I have to update my blog post.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks: I used the mixin approach

Comment: @Ralph - How ? I am in exact same situation.

Comment: @happybuddha: read the linked article: in a very brief abstract: create the (abstract) Mixin class that contains only this line `@JsonProperty("width") abstract long getId();` and then "assign" the mixin: `objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Child.class, MixIn.class);`

Answer (score 8):

If you put the annotations on the getters (instead directly on the fields), you can override the `getId()` method (if it's not final in the superclass) and add an annotation to it.

```
class Parent {
  public long getId(){...};
  ...
}

@JsonAutoDetect(JsonMethod.NONE)
class Child extends Parent {

    private String title;

    @JsonProperty
    public String getTitle() {...}

    @Override
    @JsonProperty
    public long getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the most pragmatic way. But I used the approach mentioned by Programmer Bruce because it separates the different concerns.

Comment: Oh, yeah!  Methods can be overridden.